# iptables: Access to nat via mac address

Tags: iptables, centos6, nat

I have a server with two interfaces, LAN and WAN.
How to allow access to NAT from local addresses only through the MAC address via iptables?

I tried so but it did not work out:

```
iptables -P FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m mac --mac-source 48:43:7c:25:60:3a -j ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using "-P" ? It is suppossed that "-P" is to set the general policy of a chain:

```
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

For custom rules you should -A (append) or -I (insert).

What you want could something like:

```
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m mac --mac-source 48:43:7c:25:60:3a -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j DROP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Of course you need to have forwarding activated: `echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Comment: We have more than 2500 hosts in LAN. We want to register the MAC address of each device in the rules

Comment: I edited my answer. But it's important the order of the rules. So your script should add macs before the DROP policy. If you need to add a new one, you should insert the new one using `iptables -I`to insert it before instead of -A (append)